# Java 8 Lambda Expressions not working

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying out the following code and compiling it using JDK 1.8.0_66. My code seems to be syntactically correct, did I miss something?

```
interface Executable {
    void execute();
}

class Runner {
    public void run(Executable e) {
        System.out.println("Executing code block!");
        e.execute();
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = new Runner();

        runner.run(new Executable() {
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("IN ANONYMOUS CLASS EXECUTE");
            }
        });
    }

    runner.run(() -> System.out.println());

}
```

throws the following compile error:

```
App.java:25: error: <identifier> expected
        runner.run(() -> System.out.println());
                  ^
App.java:25: error: illegal start of type
        runner.run(() -> System.out.println());
                   ^
App.java:25: error: ';' expected
        runner.run(() -> System.out.println());
```

Comment: If you're getting compile errors your code is, almost by definition, NOT syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks I feel stupid! Didn't really notice that my lambda expression was outside the Main code block

Answer (score 4):

Your statement is outside the block, where the `runnner` variable is defined. Should be something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runner runner = new Runner();

    runner.run(new Executable() {
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("IN ANONYMOUS CLASS EXECUTE");
        }
    });

    runner.run(() -> System.out.println());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That line of code needs to be inside a code block. So you need to move it into the body of the `main` method:

Change

```
} // end of main

runner.run(() -> System.out.println());
```

to

```
    runner.run(() -> System.out.println());
} // end of main
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that! :)

Answer (score 0):

runner.run(() -> System.out.println()); -- is outside main method. Put the code inside the main method and it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: This answer is already expressed and realized in the main post's comments

Comment: Thanks. But i didn't notice that. Rating down is not good attitude.